# Add HTML to Page Content

Tags: filters, formatting, pages

I'm accessing a page content from outside WordPress, in a different webpage. Everything runs fine, I'm using this:

```
require("wp-load.php");
$page_id = 300;
$data = get_page($page_id);    
echo $data->the_content;
```

However, the content is different from what WordPress would output normally. For example, paragraphs which are separated by blank lines in source come just like that, without `<p>` tags. How can I get the content from a page in the same way that WordPress would print it? Should I apply some other filter or use another function to process the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed! It's a filter called 'the_content', to which numerous other functions are hooked such as the one that turns Wordpress into WordPress, oembeds, and the p tag wrapping

```
echo apply_filter('the_content',$data->the_content);
```